# Access XML's attribute in JSP

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

How to get XML's attribute posID in JSP to set as value for HTML's option tag, as there no tag for accesing attributes?

XML:

```
<vocabul>
    <PosWord posID="1">ABC</PosWord>
</vocabul>
```

JSP:

```
<x:parse xml="${sessionScope.places}" var="doc"/>
<select name="ChooseVoc">
    <x:forEach select="$doc/vocabul/PosWord" var="item">
        <option value="<x:out select="posID" />"/>
            <x:out select="Pos_Txt" />
        </option>
    </x:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<x:parse xml="${sessionScope.places}" var="doc"/>
<select name="ChooseVoc">
    <x:forEach select="$doc/vocabul/PosWord" var="item">
        <option value="<x:out select="$item/@posID" />"/>
            <x:out select="$item" />
        </option>
     </x:forEach>
</select>
```

works for me